# How does a floated element take up vertical space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've read this article mentioning the use of CSS ,but I still can't understand why image number four is not below image number one, instead it's below image number three. Please help me.
Html code:

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=2"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=6"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7"></li> </ul>
```

Style:

```
li {
 float: left;
 margin: 4px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the W3C CSS 2.1 specification http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats:

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.

What might work for you in this case is to use `display: inline-block;` instead:

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=1"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=2"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=3"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=4"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=5"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x150&text=6"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=7"></li> </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but what does "a line box" mean in this situation?

Comment: I suppose the easiest way to describe a line box is to say it's a single line of text. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inlineformatting provides a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because the number two have float:left, and if is space and elements which can float on the left, they will.

The behavior you are describing, eg number 4 stacking below number 1 would rather suit inline-block